# Is K-K-K-K-A-A-A-A-4-7 a valid hand in Dou Dizhu (aka "Fighting The Landlord")?

Tags: dou-dizhu

**QUESTION**

In [dou dizhu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dou_dizhu), is `K-K-K-K-A-A-A-A-4-7` assumed to be a standard hand type?

**BACKGROUND**

I understand the '飞机带小翼' (i.e. "airplane with small wings", or consecutive triplets with added cards, for example: `K-K-K-A-A-A-4-7` ) hand type to be a valid hand by way of the [Pagat rules](https://www.pagat.com/climbing/doudizhu.html) and by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dou_dizhu).

Wikipedia also refers to a hand type called '航天飞机带小翼', or "space shuttle with small wings", which consists of consecutive quads with added cards (e.g. `K-K-K-K-A-A-A-A-4-7`).  I'm not sure where to find an official, standardized set of rules for dou dizhu because I don't speak Chinese, so I'm trying to figure out if the quads thing is a regional variant.

Comment: I can create either of those tags. Should I go ahead and create dou-dizhu, or would landlord be more approprite to an English audience? (Considering we do still call mahjong as such)

Comment: @doppelgreener Awesome - either works, thanks.  `dou-dizhu` might be more appropriate.

Comment: Tag created! Would you like to [create a brief tag wiki summary for it](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dou-dizhu)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, no, quads cannot be sequenced, let alone "with wings".

That said, Dou Dizhu, like many other games of Chinese origin, is a game with many local variantions and house rules. (Most variations comes in how the landlord is determined.)

While I will not be surprized if some people play with quad squences, it would rarely make a difference because

1. it is already unusual that a player has an "airplane" or a bomb, having two consecutive quads are much rarer. (By my calculations, ~.1% for the landlord and ~.02% for the peasants)
2. like the quad sets ("quad with two" and "quad with two pairs"), it is seldom advantageous to play it and give up the bomb

At least in my area, "space shuttle" (穿梭機) refers to a sequence of three triplets.